# how to call a JS function in loop with same id in Ruby and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

this is code in my View of ruby

```
<%@user_credentials.each do |user| %>
    <strong>Password:</strong>
    <input type="password" value="<%=user.encrypted_password %>" id="myInput">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">  ShowPassword
<% end %>
```

and in javascript file JS function

```
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
        x.type = "text";
    } else {
        x.type = "password";
    }
}
```

i want to call myFunction() each time
i'm missing something it may b because of some id
please guaid me with right way how to handle this

Comment: Did you just try to debug it?

Comment: If there is some thing related to ruby on rails, maybe you should show your HTML template. I can smell as you mention a loop, that you have multiple HTML tags with the same `id`, which is not cool since an id is an identifier, and should be unique.

Comment: now i just put the whole html

Comment: Well sjahan is right you are iterating over user_credentials so the there will be more then 1 input with the same id if you have more then 1 user.

Comment: how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: Just don't set a constant as `id` don't set `myInput` for each iteration. Add at least the index in it, so you have different `id`. IDs are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi why don't you iterate using each_with_index, in that way you will not have repeated id's

```
<%@user_credentials.each_with_index do |checklist, index| %>
 <strong>Password:</strong>
 <input type="password" value="<%=user.encrypted_password %>" id="input-<%= index %>">
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">  ShowPassword
<% end %>
```